# What causes my pipes to disappear in the middle of my Unity game camera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have written code to delete the pipes once they are out of the game camera view but for some reason the pipes are disappearing once they reach the center of the camera instead of once they are out of the players view

I have written three scripts so far...

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UIElements;

    public class PipeScript : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float moveSpeed;
        public float deadZone = -35;

        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
        
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            transform.position = transform.position + (Vector3.left * moveSpeed) * Time.deltaTime;
        
            if (transform.position.x < deadZone)
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
            } 

        }
    

    }
```

... above is one of the two scripts i have written for the pipe in this script i have the command to destroy the gameobject once it reaches the deadzone. in the next script is for the spawner that spawns the pipes...

```
    using JetBrains.Annotations;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEditor.Experimental.GraphView;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class PipeSpawnerScript : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject pipe;
        public float spawnRate;
        private float timer = 0;
        public float heightOffset = 10;
    

        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            spawnPipe();
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            if (timer < spawnRate )
            {
                timer = timer + Time.deltaTime;
            }
            else
            {
                spawnPipe();
                timer = 0;
            }
        
   
        }
        void spawnPipe()
        {
            float lowestPoint = transform.position.y - heightOffset;
            float highestPoint = transform.position.y + heightOffset;

            Instantiate(pipe,new Vector3(transform.position.x,Random.Range(lowestPoint,     highestPoint),0),transform.rotation);
        }
    }
```

... these scripts result in the pipe being destroyed in the middle of the game camera instead of out of view I am unsure of what the try next and have searched the internet and cannot find an answer.
I have also tried the onBecameInvisible method and the program wouldnt destroy the gameObject at all.

Comment: if you initially had `public float deadZone = 0;` in your code, but changed it later to `-35;`, the inspector might still have `0` serialized. You can use `...` -> `reset` or just change it in the inspector. This is often overlooked

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what you want. For future reference, consider stating your purpose when asking questions. **Here are the two ideas I have of what I think you need:**

I think what you want is [occlusion culling](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html). Occlusion culling boosts your performance, and suspends game objects so that they disappear and appear according to player's view.

**If you actually DO want to remove the pipes entirely, try the following:**

In your script, one of the things you can do is a physics.overlapsphere with a large radius (for distance), and manipulate the arc of the sphere to exclude the player's vision. You can then get all of the gameobjects with a specific tag (for example "pipes"), put them in a list, and destroy them using a foreach() loop.

Hope this helps.